# using jpeg-6b, error error: too many arguments to function ‘void jpeg_CreateDecompress()’

Tags: c++, jpeg, libjpeg

Our code uses jpeg libraries and worked in older configurations but recently I've been trying to make it work with a local jpeg-6b package and am getting this error, "too many arguments to function 'void jpeg_CreateDecompress()". I made a simple application to demonstrate:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include "jpeg-6b/jpeglib.h"
main()
{
    struct jpeg_decompress_struct cinfo;

    jpeg_create_decompress(&cinfo);
}
```

And compiling gets this:

```
gcc jtest.cpp -Ijpeg-6b -Ljpeg-6b -ljpeg
In file included from jtest.cpp:2:0:
jtest.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
jpeg-6b/jpeglib.h:899:52: error: too many arguments to function ‘void jpeg_CreateDecompress()’
      (size_t) sizeof(struct jpeg_decompress_struct))
                                                    ^
jtest.cpp:7:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘jpeg_create_decompress’
     jpeg_create_decompress(&cinfo);
     ^
jpeg-6b/jpeglib.h:902:14: note: declared here
 EXTERN(void) jpeg_CreateDecompress JPP((j_decompress_ptr cinfo,
```

In jpeglib.h, jpeg_create_decompress is a macro that takes one argument and expands to jpeg_CreateDecompress which has 3 arguments, using the cinfo as the first argument and filling in the other two. Looks to me like the argument counts are correct:

```
#define jpeg_create_decompress(cinfo) \
    jpeg_CreateDecompress((cinfo), JPEG_LIB_VERSION, \
                          (size_t) sizeof(struct jpeg_decompress_struct))
EXTERN(void) jpeg_CreateCompress JPP((j_compress_ptr cinfo,
                                      int version, size_t structsize));
EXTERN(void) jpeg_CreateDecompress JPP((j_decompress_ptr cinfo,
                                        int version, size_t structsize));
```

This is just jpeg-6b as downloaded off google, configured via "configure" before running "make libjpeg.a. I haven't changed any of the jpeg-6b source code. Probably something stupid but any ideas?

This is on Ubuntu 14.04.1.

Comment: It compiles for me, on Debian Jessie, after having used `apt-get install libjpeg-dev` and fixed up the `#include` statements. Let's debug. How many arguments is your compiler expecting? Two? One? Zero? What happens if you call `jpeg_CreateDecompress` directly?

Comment: Sorry for letting this one hang. calling jpeg_CreateDecompress directly had the same result. But I resolved it in my case by copying / modifying jconfig.vc (visual C jconfig) -- modification was to delete the #define USE_SETMODE line. This works in Ubuntu 14.04 at least... don't know why it works better than the one created by configure doesn't, but it does so I've moved on.